# I would like to write ethernet datas to label

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a problem.I have an ethernet connection in ethernet class.I have to write data's (coming from ethernet) to ui label.Here is my ethernet class run method.

```
void ethernetthread::run(){

   printf("Connecting to hello world sever");
   void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
   void *requester=zmq_socket(context ,ZMQ_REQ);
   zmq_connect(requester,"tcp://localhost:5555");
   int request_nbr;
   for(request_nbr=0; request_nbr!=10; request_nbr++){
      char buffer[10];
      printf("Sending Hello %d\n" ,request_nbr);
      zmq_send(requester ,"DERGISOKAK",10,0);
      zmq_recv(requester ,buffer,10,0);

      zmq_recv(requester,buffer,10,0);
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      printf("%c :",buffer[i]);
      qDebug()<<"buffer["<<i<<"] : "<<buffer[i];
   }
   printf("Received World %d\n",request_nbr);
   }
   zmq_close(requester);
   zmq_ctx_destroy(context);

  }
```

Here is my MainWindow Class

```
   MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new 
   Ui::MainWindow)
   { 

    timerCounter = new QTimer();
    connect(timerCounter,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(timer_label_test_slot()));
    timerCounter->start(1000);
   }

   void MainWindow::timer_label_test_slot(){
   this->ui->label->setText(QString::number(counter));
   counter++;

   }
```

So how can I connect this two classes? How can I show ethernet datas to ui label?
Maybe I should make signal slot mechanism between two seperate classes.

Comment: First, [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please. Second: I assume your send/receive runs in a thread, then just emit a signal when the data arrived, and connect it to a slot in main thread that renders text in QLabel. And read how to use ZMQ, context is not supposed to be created and destroyed every time, also there is a C++ wrapper available.

Comment: can you send a document or explanation of c++ wrapper ?

Comment: https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq